# How to pass child component data into parent

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have 3 components, 2 child and 1 parent.
I have save button in parent component, for getting child data in parent, I have tried this:

```
<div class="border border-dark p-1 m-1">
  <basic-details
    *ngIf="customerData"
    [formType]="formType"
    [customerDetails]="customerData"
    #customerDetails
  ></basic-details>
</div>
<div class="border border-dark p-1 m-1">
  <verification-details
    *ngIf="customerData"
    [formType]="formType"
    [customerDetailsForKyc]="customerData"
    #customerDetailsForKyc
  ></verification-details>
</div>

<div class="row main justify-content-center">
  <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="save(customerDetails, customerDetailsForKyc)">Save</button>
  <button class="btn btn-primary ml-2" (click)="cancel()">Cancel</button>
</div>
```

> ts file

```
save(basic, kyc) {
    console.log('basic', basic);
    console.log('kyc', kyc);
  }
```

For `basic-details` component, I am getting proper data in my parent component in save button click, but for `verification-details` I am getting following error:

In both child component I am getting data using @Input() like this:

> for basic component:

```
@Input() customerDetails: ICustomerDetailsData;
```

> for verification component

```
@Input() customerDetailsForKyc;
```

Is something I am doing wrong?

Comment: Can you share TS and html for both child component?

Comment: I have tried for you but It worked for both child component for me [LINK STACKBLITZ](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-two-way-data-binding-between-parent-and-child-co-acqylp?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts). Please let me know.

Comment: can you please give the 3 ts files of each component

Comment: @Linker Added please check, is there something I did wrong?

Comment: In both component I am using the same data for @Input(), is this problem?

Comment: @techguy I'm afraid that this isn't enough to understand all the situation, if you can share all the content of the files it'll be better.
Though, try to add : ICustomerDetailsData; also for the second input

Comment: @techguy please check my answer and let me know. If you still facing problem. You can give a sample in Stackblitz where I can check. Best wishes. :-)

Answer (score 1):

I have a working example of your code, two child and one parent. As you described in your question, I have used almost similar things in my code. You did not mention about `[formType]="formType"`, that's why I did not use it. Please check my code. It is working in StackBlitz ==> [Angular two way data binding between parent and child co acqylp](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-two-way-data-binding-between-parent-and-child-co-acqylp)

```
import { Component, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `<app-children [(data)]="message"  
              [customerDetails]="customerData"
              #customerDetails></app-children>
             <br><br>
             <app-children2 [(data)]="message2" 
              
             [customerDetailsForKyc]="customerData"
             #customerDetailsForKyc></app-children2>
            <div>Parent: {{message}}
            <br>
            <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="save(customerDetails, customerDetailsForKyc)">Save</button>
            </div>`,
})

export class AppComponent {
  public message: string;
  public message2: string;
  customerData:ICustomerDetailsData={color:'TTT',width:15};
  ngOnInit() {
    this.message = 'Original message'
    this.message2 = 'Original message2'
  }
  save(basic, kyc) {
    console.log('basic', basic);
    console.log('kyc', kyc);
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-children',
  template: `<div>Children: {{data}}</div> 
              <br>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name"
     
              [(ngModel)]="data" >
              <br>
             <a (click)="changeMessage('Children message')">Click me!</a>`
})

export class ChildComponent {
  @Input() public data: string;
  @Input() customerDetails: ICustomerDetailsData;
  @Output() dataChange= new EventEmitter<string>();
  changeMessage(message: string) {
    this.data = message;
    this.dataChange.emit(this.data);
  }
}

 @Component({
  selector: 'app-children2',
  template: `<div>Children: {{data}}</div> 
             <a (click)="changeMessage('Children message')">Click me!</a>`
})

export class ChildComponentNew {
    @Input() customerDetailsForKyc;
  @Input() public data: string;
  @Output() dataChange= new EventEmitter<string>();
  changeMessage(message: string) {
    this.data = message;
    this.dataChange.emit(this.data);
  }
}
interface ICustomerDetailsData {
  color?: string;
  width?: number;
}
```

Comment: You have created changeMessage() in child component, But I don't have any button in child component, I want to get the data of child component without clicking any button in child component, I have save button only in parent component

Comment: @techguy you did not need any `<a (click)="changeMessage('Children message')">Click me!</a>` in child. Please check the give link now . I have updated it . Still it's working when I press Save button. [LINK](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-two-way-data-binding-between-parent-and-child-co-acqylp)

Answer (score 0):

Original Text

1. Your method: `save(customerDetails, customerDetailsForKyc)"` uses as arguments template variables. It is wrong, because they have other goals.
   "Template variables help you use data from one part of a template in another part of the template. With template variables, you can perform tasks such as respond to user input or finely tune your application's forms."
   [Template variables | Angular](https://angular.io/guide/template-reference-variables).
2. If you want to send data in the parent component (pass child component data into parent) so use to decorator @Output
   [Sharing data between child and parent directives and components | Angular](https://angular.io/guide/inputs-outputs)

Comment: I did with @Output but, in my case there is no button in my child component, I have only single save button in parent component, On click of that save button I want to get all the child component data

Answer (score 0):

One other option to get data from child to parent is to use @ViewChild decorator in order to inject child component to parent. So, when save button is clicked you should be able to take data of your child components. Check [ViewChild
| Angular](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild)